# How to remove the first number before date to bring this dataset to get re-sampled in Python?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

```
import numpy as np
import math
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
gold = pd.read_csv("CSV.csv")
import datetime as dt
```

I try to plot the squared return of the gold price. My problem is that it still does not want to resample.

which now looks like this:

```
Date       Open       High        Low      Close  Adj Close  Volume
0   2017-11-15  24.459999  24.850000  24.459999  24.629999  24.629999  120900
1   2017-11-16  24.459999  24.780001  24.459999  24.680000  24.680000  133900
2   2017-11-17  24.559999  25.040001  24.549999  24.969999  24.969999  137100
3   2017-11-20  24.959999  25.059999  24.730000  24.799999  24.799999   61500
4   2017-11-21  24.860001  25.090000  24.549999  25.070000  25.070000   95400
5   2017-11-22  25.180000  25.200001  24.969999  25.010000  25.010000   38800
6   2017-11-24  25.110001  25.110001  24.570000  24.740000  24.740000   35700
7   2017-11-27  24.740000  25.059999  24.740000  24.930000  24.930000   68900
8   2017-11-28  25.030001  25.290001  24.879999  25.219999  25.219999   79100
9   2017-11-29  25.240000  25.860001  24.809999  25.790001  25.790001  139900
10  2017-11-30  26.010000  26.030001  25.480000  25.620001  25.620001  105800
11  2017-12-01  25.709999  25.790001  25.290001  25.670000  25.670000   87800
12  2017-12-04  25.889999  26.059999  25.709999  25.920000  25.920000   66400

gold['sq_log_ret'] = np.log(gold.Close).diff(1)*np.log(gold.Close).diff(1)



gold['sq_log_ret'].resample('W', how='mean').plot.line()
plt.xlabel("time")
plt.ylabel("squared log returns")
plt.title("mean sq_log_ret in two weeks periode")
plt.show()
```

I get a type error like this:

> Only valid with DatetimeIndex, TimedeltaIndex or PeriodIndex, but got
>   an instance of 'RangeIndex'.

I think these numbers from 0 to 12 are the problem, but I can't figure out how to remove them for large dataset. Any help or thoughts would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IIUC, you don't have an index in your dataframe. According to the [docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.resample.html), you should have a datetime index for pandas resampling. Here's what I did and it worked for me,
Created an index converting to pandas `datetime`

```
gold.index = pd.to_datetime(gold.Date)
```

And then, ran the same code you have,

```
gold['sq_log_ret'].resample('W', how='mean').plot.line()
plt.xlabel("time")
plt.ylabel("squared log returns")
plt.title("mean sq_log_ret in two weeks periode")
plt.show()
```

Output,

[image]